# How to detect in Java if string contains Cyrillic?

Tags: java, regex

I want to detect if a string contains Cyrillic letters.

In PHP I did something like this:

```
preg_match('/\p{Cyrillic}+/ui', $text)
```

What would work the same in Java?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Pattern.matches(".*\\p{InCyrillic}.*", text)
```

You may also avoid a regex and use the class [`Character.UnicodeBlock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html):

```
for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    if(Character.UnicodeBlock.of(text.charAt(i)).equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC)) {
        // contains Cyrillic
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the performance is better if I avoid using a regex? I'm on Android if it makes a difference.

Comment: @knezmilos I don't think you will notice a big difference (it depends on the size of the text -- you can try measuring both ways). I prefer the second way because it's more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to do the same with streams in java 8:

```
text.chars()
        .mapToObj(Character.UnicodeBlock::of)
        .filter(Character.UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC::equals)
        .findAny()
        .ifPresent(character -> ));
```

Or another way, keeping the index:

```
char[] textChars = text.toCharArray();
IntStream.range(0, textChars.length)
                 .filter(index -> Character.UnicodeBlock.of(textChars[index])
                                .equals(Character.UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC))
                 .findAny() // can use findFirst()
                 .ifPresent(index -> );
```

*Please note:* I'm using char array here rather than String due to performance advantage of getting an element by index.

Answer (score 1):

The above examples using `UnicodeBlock` will work just fine, but can also use the [`Character.UnicodeScript`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.UnicodeScript.html) `enum` if you prefer:

```
boolean containsCyrillic = "Your String Goes Here".codePoints()
    .mapToObj(Character.UnicodeScript::of)
    .anyMatch(Character.UnicodeScript.CYRILLIC::equals);
```

If you don't trust your input, you can be more defensive using [`Character.isValidCodePoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isValidCodePoint(int)):

```
boolean containsCyrillic =
    "Your Untrusted String Goes Here".codePoints()
        .filter(Character::isValidCodePoint)
        .mapToObj(Character.UnicodeScript::of)
        .anyMatch(s -> s == Character.UnicodeScript.CYRILLIC);
```

If you're interested in analyzing the various scripts in your text, for example to determine the predominant script of your text, you can keep track of the number of code points in various scripts:

```
Map<Character.UnicodeScript,Long> scripts = 
    "Your Untrusted String Goes Here".codePoints()
        .filter(Character::isValidCodePoint)
        .mapToObj(Character.UnicodeScript::of)
        .collect(groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            counting()));
```

We can also be a titch more efficient and use an [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html), since `Character.UnicodeScript` is an `enum`:

```
Map<Character.UnicodeScript,Long> scripts = 
    "Your Untrusted String Goes Here".codePoints()
        .filter(Character::isValidCodePoint)
        .mapToObj(Character.UnicodeScript::of)
        .collect(groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            () -> new EnumMap<>(Character.UnicodeScript.class),
            counting()));
```

If you're just interested in the majority vote, then you can try this:

```
Optional<Character.UnicodeScript> predominantScript = 
    "Your Untrusted String Goes Here".codePoints()
        .filter(Character::isValidCodePoint)
        .mapToObj(Character.UnicodeScript::of)
        .filter(s -> s != Character.UnicodeScript.COMMON
            && s != Character.UnicodeScript.INHERITED
            && s != Character.UnicodeScript.UNKNOWN)
        .collect(groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            () -> new EnumMap<>(Character.UnicodeScript.class),
            counting()))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(
            Comparator
            .<Map.Entry<Character.UnicodeScript, Long>>comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .reversed()
            .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .findFirst();
```

We filter out `Character.UnicodeScript.COMMON`, `Character.UnicodeScript.INHERITED`, and `Character.UnicodeScript.UNKNOWN` because they are "catch-all" categories used for shared code points, mapped to all code points, or simply unrecognized code points (per [the spec](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Classification_by_Script)), as opposed to individual scripts.